# LINQ not refreshing the data

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-sql-database, iis-express

I have a MVC 4 website with Azure SQL and they behave strange. When I am running it locally (IIS Express), I have one LINQ query to my database that returns the same data even if it changed and I can see it different through a separate query. I am really wondering what's going on.

The controller function I use is

```
    public int GetNotificationTotalCount(int userId)
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        var tmp = (from entry in _db.NotificationCounts
                   where entry.UserId == userId
                   select entry).FirstOrDefault();

        if (tmp != null) // return zeros
            cnt = tmp.FlagsCount + tmp.RepliesCount;

        return cnt;
    }
```

, where _*db* is my DataContext and the LINQ returns *IQueryable*.

I know it caches the data because of *IQueriable* but I am exiting this function and the tmp object is supposed to be destroyed. Or so I think.

Is it?

Comment: What browser are you testing this on? I found that sometimes IE caches the data and you need to add an attribute ([CacheControl(HttpCacheability.NoCache), HttpGet]) to your method to prevent this.

Comment: I see the issue in both IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your context life span is too long. `DataContext` instances are supposed to be short-lived. The `entry` object is cached in in, so when you try to fetch it another time it is taken from the cache unless you explicitly refresh the object.

```
public int GetNotificationTotalCount(int userId)
{
    using(var db = new MyDataContext())
    {
        return (from entry in db.NotificationCounts
                where entry.UserId == userId
                select entry.FlagsCount + entry.RepliesCount)
               .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0;
    }
}
```